# mysql create trigger ON INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

Suppose I have the following table

```
create table try  ( name varchar(10), username varchar(10))
```

Is it possible to have a trigger 'ON INSERT' to set username=user() ?

I tried doing

```
create trigger userIns ON INSERT on try for each row set new.username=user();
```

but this gives some syntax error

I have seen documentation about BEFORE INSERT,AFTER INSERT. How about ON INSERT?

if not, whats my best bet?

Comment: just use after insert and correct syntax, it's probably what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the above was my problem. I was really looking for an ON INSERT trigger - but it does not exist in MYSQL. So I used BEFORE INSERT and that works fine

```
create trigger userIns BEFORE INSERT on try for each row set new.CREATED_BY=user();
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event
ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...
END
```

Your syntax is wrong in `trigger_time` part.

> Trigger activation time can be BEFORE or AFTER. You must specify the
>   activation time when you define a trigger. You use BEFORE keyword if
>   you want to process action prior to the change is made on the table
>   and AFTER if you need to process action after change are made.

Try this :

```
create trigger userIns BEFORE INSERT on try for each row set new.username=user();
```

More : [MYSQL Trigger Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Correct Syntax is

```
Create Trigger trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event
on table_name
for each row
begin
....

end
```

Trigger_time => Before | After
trigger_event => Insert | Update | Delete

Please check

```
create trigger userIns INSERT on try for each row begin set new.username=user() end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to set the delimiter to something other than ';' before you begin the trigger code.  Put the new delimiter after 'end' and then change the delimiter back to ';' after you are done.